# Determinant of a matrix with two identical rows is zero

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, field-theory, determinant

Given an arbitrary field $F = (F, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$, the book I am reading defines a function $d$ on $F^{n \times n}$, the set of $n$-dimensional square matrices over $F$, to be a determinant function if it satisfies the following:

1. $d(I) = 1$, where $I$ is the identity matrix
2. $d(E_{ij}A) = -d(A)$, where $E_{ij}$ is the elementary matrix that, when acting from the left, exchanges row $i$ and row $j$
3. $d(E_{i;c}A) = c \cdot d(A)$, where $E_{i;c}$ is the elementary matrix that, when acting from the left, multiplies row $i$ by $c$
4. $d(E_{ij;c}A) = d(A)$, where $E_{ij;c}$ is the elementary matrix that, when acting from the left, adds $c$ times row $j$ to row $i$
5. $d(A)=0$ for every matrix A having at least one row full of zeros.

My question is on how to prove the fact that if a matrix $A$ has two identical rows, say row $i$ and row $j$, and $d$ is a determinant function, then $d(A)=0$.

I would just argue that if $A$ is such a matrix, then $E_{ij,-1}A$ has the $i^{th}$ identically equal to zero, so that $d(A) = d(E_{ij,-1}A) = 0$, where the first equality follows from $4.$ and the second from $5.$.

On the other end, the mentioned book provides a proof that distinguishes between the case $\text{char}(F) = 2$ and $\text{char}(F) > 2$. In the first case, it argues like in my proof with $E_{ij,1}$ (but in $\text{char}(F) = 2$, we have $1 = -1$, so that I would say the proofs are identical). In the second case, it notices that $A = E_{ij}A$ so that, by $2.$, $d(A) = -d(A)$ and then $d(A) = 0$. I perfectly agree with this proof.

Is my simpler proof correct?

If yes, do you have an idea on why the book is making an unnecessary distinction and providing an unnecessary heavy proof?

If not, where is the error in my proof?

Comment: Since row exchanges change the sign and two rows are identical the determinant must satisfy $x=-x$ since the left is before the exchange and the right is after the row exchange, which is the same matrix. This implies $x=0$.

Comment: The book uses 2. for the proof, you use 4. and 5. 
The proof using statement 2 only works for if $\text{char}(F) \neq 2$

Comment: Slight typo it should be $n^2$ dimensional square matrices over $F$. Btw you can write definition of determinant more compactly by introducing notion like $n$-linear and alternating.

Comment: Thx - You probably misunderstood me. I understand and agree with his proof (both cases). What I do not understand is why he decided to split the case char=2 and char>2. I think my proof is valid for both cases, in which case it would be simpler. But is my proof correct *both* in char=2 and char>2?